# JavaScript - Modify arguments before executing function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Given I have a function called `sum` module imported from a 3rd party module `Calculator`. Here's how I use it:

```
Calculator.sum(1, 2) // returns 3
```

I don't know the implementation of `Calculator.sum`. What if I want to modify the arguments passed to `Calculator.sum` before executing `sum`, so that instead of taking the original numbers (1, 2, 3, etc), `sum` will take their squared values (1, 4, 9, etc) ? For example:

```
Calculator.sum(1, 2) // returns 5
Calculator.sum(2, 3) // returns 13
Calculator.sum(3, 4) // returns 25
```

**Note:** This is just an example of my actual problem, I don't actually need a `Calculator.sum` function to calculate sum of squares

Comment: Why would you want to modify the method instead of just passing the modified values into it? Its called `sum`. Just call the method with the modified values or create a new method for it. the `Math` "namespace" have all the functions you need for that.

Comment: It's just an example of my problem. Passing the modified values to it is straightforward but in my actual function, I have to modify a lot of existed unit tests

Comment: Yes, but if your unit tests are for a `sum` method that you expect to not actually `sum` you have either created unit tests for the wrong version or you might have to consider renaming a few things...  
I would recommend creating a new method in the `Calculator` object if that is what you feel you need, a method with a better name, that does what you wish. Not replace the `sum` method with something that is NOT `sum` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply decorate the original function with you extra functionality, then call the original function with whatever values you wish.

If you are going to do something like this, you should really define a different function eg, `calulator.squareAdd`.

```js
// this is your library object
const Calculator = {
  sum: (...args) => args.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
}

console.log(
  'before decoration',
  Calculator.sum(1, 2)
)

// save a reference to the original function
const origSum = Calculator.sum
// decorate the sum function with your own function
Calculator.sum = function(...args) {
  return origSum.apply(Calculator, args.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2)))
}

// call the decorated function

console.log(
  'after decoration',
  Calculator.sum(1, 2), // returns 5
  Calculator.sum(2, 3), // returns 13
  Calculator.sum(3, 4) // returns 25
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just store it under another name and overwrite it ?

```
Calculator.sum_stored = Calculator.sum;
Calculator.sum = function(a,b){
    return Calculator.sum_stored(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(b));
};
```

Then you can just call `Calculator.sum` as you wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the arguments in side the method like this ->

```
Calculator.sum(a,b) {
return a*a + b*b;
}
```

And if you want your method to be flexible then you can pass a third argument that will identify what operation needs to be performed on the arguments.

```
Calculator.sum(a,b,'square'){
    //use switch case here to return the correct result.
}
```